# Rails: SQLite3::SQLException: near "from": syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an issue with a sort by year filter on my rails app; when i attempt to select a year from my view, the app crashes with this error: SQLite3::SQLException: near "from": syntax error

The code(passed down from the previous dev who has moved on) for the filter in my control is this:

```
    @posts = Post.where('extract(year from sort_date) = ?', params[:year])
                 .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
                 .order('sort_date DESC')
    render 'index'
  end
```

i might be wrong but i am assuming it's the `'extract(year from sort_date) = ?'` in the code? but i am unsure, also for reference the reference parameter is: {"year"=>"2017"}

I attempted to make it look more like a postgres query("EXTRACT(year FROM sort_date) = ?" but still it fails, with the exact same SQL error(Rails: SQLite3::SQLException: near "from")

Comment: Was it ever working? Or did you inherit it broken?

Comment: @Beartech Inherited it broken but it's been on the canvan board to fix for at least a year prior to me joining

Answer (score 2):

SQLITE3 does not support the extract() function. You have to use strftime().

```
@posts = Post.where("strftime('%Y', sort_date) = ?", params[:year])
                 .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
                 .order('sort_date DESC')
    render 'index'
  end
```

Comment: that worked! though now it's throwing a similar error: `SQLite3::SQLException: [:year]`

Comment: It works on mine. Can you try hard coding a value for `params[:year]` and see what happens? i.e. `Post.where("strftime('%Y', sort_date) = ?", '2017')`

Comment: yep, hard coding works... though nothing shows up so i'm assuming possibly the params[:years] not working is due to the database im calling from being empty

Comment: I wouldn't assume that. SQL is returning an error with the literal value of [:year]. That tells me that for some reason SQL is getting passed the string "[:year]" instead of getting a value. Not sure why. But if you set `params[:year] = nil` you will see that it just returns an empty result, no error. So being nil or empty is not an error situation.

Comment: got it working, it was a single misplaced ' on my end on the sort_date! thanks for the help :)